# Customsize Background in Plot within Mathematica

Tags: background, wolfram-mathematica, plot, customization

Considering:

```
ListPlot[Range[10], 
         Background -> Gray, 
         PlotLabel -> "I don`t want the background here !"]
```

[image]

Is there any way to have the background applied solely to the actual plotting zone?

Not on the axis, not behind the label. So basically to the rectangle {{0,0},{10,10}} in that case?

EDIT: Can we do the Same using PolarListPlot?

Using Sjoerd Solution on  [From Cartesian Plot to Polar Histogram using  Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419562/angles-polar-coordinate-in-mathematica):

```
dalist = {{21, 22}, {26, 13}, {32, 17}, {31, 11}, {30, 9}, 
          {25,12}, {12, 16}, {18, 20}, {13, 23}, {19, 21}, 
          {14, 16}, {14,22}, {18, 22}, {10, 22}, {17, 23}}

ScreenCenter = {20, 15}

ListPolarPlot[{ArcTan[##],EuclideanDistance[##]} & @@@ (# - ScreenCenter & /@ dalist), 
               PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> False, 
               PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
               BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
               FontSize -> 12}, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize -> 0.02}]
```

[image]

Comment: Here are other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303500/mathematica-matlab-like-figure-plot

Comment: Undocumented option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True/False} ` might help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ListPlot[Range[10], PlotLabel -> "I don`t want the background here !",
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Prolog -> {Gray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this is it ! And it works as such despite all my customized options ! Thank You !

Comment: I had difficulty using this approach for grey backgrounds if the gridlines were white. I suspect `GridLines` is conceptually "behind" `Prolog`.

Comment: @Verbeia That is true. The documentation says: "Grid lines are always drawn below all the graphics". I guess a workaround would be to draw lines at the major ticks manually either as an `Epilog` or combine with `Show`.

Comment: @Verbeia Use undocumented option [`Method->{"GridLinesInFront"->True}`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/11783ce8923d76b4).

Comment: @Alexey Popkov - excellent idea, but don't they then go in front of the plotted lines as well? One of my recent questions relates to trying to replicate the institutional style of my current employer, but a few years ago I tried to do so for another organisation where I used to work, which also has a very particular style for its graphs.

Comment: @Verbeia Yes, the grid lines will go in front of the plotted lines. If you do not want it you could make background semi-transparent: `ListPlot[Range[10],PlotLabel->"I don't want the background here !",Frame->{True,True,False,False},AxesOrigin->{0,0},Prolog->{Gray,Opacity[0.5],Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}],Scaled[{1,1}]]},GridLines->Automatic]`.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov - try it with white gridlines.

Comment: @Verbeia For having white gridlines you probably have to define them via graphics primitives explicitly.

Comment: @Verbeia Another possibility is to use `Inset` with automatically choosen `GridLines`:  `Show[Graphics[{Gray,Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}],Scaled[{1,1}]]}],Graphics[Inset[Graphics[{},PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}},GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->{{Thick,White},{Thick,White}},Method->{"GridLinesInFront"->True}],Center,Center,Scaled[{1,1}]]],ListLinePlot[Range[10],PlotStyle->{Thick,Red}]]`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Labeled` as in

```
Labeled[
  ListPlot[Range[10], Background -> Gray,
  PlotLabel -> "I don`t want the background here !"],
  "So place the label here", Top]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[Range[10], 
         Background -> Gray, 
         PlotLabel -> Style["I don`t want the background here !",
                            Background -> White ]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: I think the req is _Not on the axis, not behind the label._

Comment: Thank you WReach,I am sorry I was not clear, I hope the Edit makes it better. What I want is some background just on the plotting zone.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
Show[Graphics[{Pink, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]}], 
 ListPlot[Range[10]], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Perhaps better

```
c = RandomInteger[100, 10];
ListPlot[c,  Prolog -> {Pink, Rectangle[{0, Min@c}, {Length@c, Max@c}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, however now i lose all my plot options :-(. This is where I am trying to apply that. I don`t know if you can see the problem without the defintion of allRTbyConsistency and plotOptionsXX : Show[
 Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4.5, 1.6}]}],
 ListPlot[((Mean /@ (allRTbyConsistency[[All, #]] // Transpose)) & /@Range[3]),
 plotOptionsXX["Total RT by Consistency", "Response Time Total", 
   "Consistency Index", Lighter[Red, #] & /@ {.1, .5, .9}], 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.5, 4.5}, {0.5, 1.6}}, 
  Background -> White, Frame -> True], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 3/4
 ]

Comment: Better alternative: `Show[Graphics[{Pink,Rectangle[{0,0},Scaled@{1,1}]}],ListPlot[Range[10]],Axes->True,AspectRatio->1/2,PlotLabel->"I don't want the background here !"]`.

Comment: Or using `Prolog`: `ListPlot[Range[10],Axes->True,AxesOrigin->{0,0},AspectRatio->1/2,PlotLabel->"I don't want the background here !",Prolog->{Pink,Rectangle[{0,0},Scaled@{1,1}]}]`.