# From Cartesian Plot to Polar Histogram using  Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, angle

Please Consider:

```
dalist={{21, 22}, {26, 13}, {32, 17}, {31, 11}, {30, 9}, 
        {25, 12}, {12, 16}, {18, 20}, {13, 23}, {19, 21}, 
        {14, 16}, {14, 22}, {18,22}, {10, 22}, {17, 23}}


ScreenCenter = {20, 15}

FrameXYs = {{4.32, 3.23}, {35.68, 26.75}}

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle @@ FrameXYs, 
          Black, Point@dalist, Red, Disk[ScreenCenter, .5]}]
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to compute, for each point, its angle in a coordinate system such as :

[image]

Above is the Deisred output, those are frequency count of point given a particular "Angle Bin".
Once I know how to compute the angle i should be able to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematica has a special plot function for this purpose: `ListPolarPlot`. You need to convert your x,y pairs to theta, r pairs, for instance as follows:

```
ListPolarPlot[{ArcTan[##], EuclideanDistance[##]} & @@@ (#-ScreenCenter & /@ dalist), 
          PolarAxes -> True, 
          PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
          Joined -> False, 
          PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
          BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold,FontSize -> 12}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize -> 0.02}
]
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

As requested per comment, polar histograms can be made as follows:

```
maxScale = 100;
angleDivisions = 20;
dAng = (2 \[Pi])/angleDivisions;
```

Some test data:

```
(counts = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 100}], {ang, angleDivisions}]) // BarChart
```

[image]

```
ListPolarPlot[{{0, maxScale}}, 
    PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
    PlotStyle -> {None}, 
    Epilog -> {Opacity[0.7], Blue, 
               Table[
                 Polygon@
                  {
                   {0, 0}, 
                   counts[[ang + 1]] {Cos[ang dAng - dAng/2],Sin[ang dAng- dAng/2]}, 
                   counts[[ang + 1]] {Cos[ang dAng + dAng/2],Sin[ang dAng+ dAng/2]}
                  },   
                 {ang, 0, angleDivisions - 1}
               ]}
]
```

[image]

A small visual improvement using `Disk` sectors instead of `Polygon`s:

```
ListPolarPlot[{{0, maxScale}}, 
    PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
    FontSize -> 12}, PlotStyle -> {None}, 
    Epilog -> {Opacity[0.7], Blue, 
               Table[
                 Disk[{0,0},counts[[ang+1]],{ang dAng-dAng/2,ang dAng+dAng/2}],       
                 {ang, 0, angleDivisions - 1}
               ]
              }
]
```

[image]

A clearer separation of the 'bars' is obtained with the addition of `EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.005]}]` in the `Epilog`. Now the numbers marking the rings still have the unnecessary decimal point trailing them. Following the plot with the replacement `/. Style[num_?MachineNumberQ, List[]] -> Style[num // Round, List[]]` removes those. The end result is:

[image]

The above plot can also be generated with `SectorChart` although this plot is primarily intended to show varying width and height of the data, and isn't fine-tuned for plots where you have fixed-width sectors and you want to highlight directions and data counts in those directions. But it can be done by using `SectorOrigin`. The problem is I take it that the midpoint of a sector codes for its direction so to have 0 deg in the mid of a sector I have to offset the origin by `\[Pi]/angleDivisions` and specify the ticks by hand as they get rotated too:

```
SectorChart[
   {ConstantArray[1, Length[counts]], counts}\[Transpose], 
   SectorOrigin -> {-\[Pi]/angleDivisions, "Counterclockwise"}, 
   PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
   PolarTicks -> 
    {
     Table[{i \[Degree] + \[Pi]/angleDivisions, i \[Degree]}, {i, 0, 345, 15}], 
     Automatic
    }, 
   ChartStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.005]}], Blue]},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 12}
 ]
```

[image]

The plot is almost the same, but it is more interactive (tooltips and so).

Comment: Thank You Sjoerd, is there such thing as a polar histogram ?

Comment: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQrKELoYtiEuAElJwl6ocF60URjADZNW1KrFQ8q4npE3mxtMWP

Comment: @belisarius Close, but no cigar  ;-)

Comment: @Simon Yep! I saw that one some time ago. I never understood the 250 upvotes for drawing a batfunction:)

Comment: @Simon but there are a lot of highly voted answers [`beyond my comprehension`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness/3956538#3956538)

Comment: @belisarius: Show off! It was a good answer and obviously useful to programmers who haven't seen the basic maths.

Comment: @Simon But just compare the conceptual problems discussed there with any good Leonid's (as an example) answer ... it's a shame

Comment: @belisarius an excellent point, as a general statement. on the other hand, what you demonstrate there is hardly a trivial observation (and is not easy to grasp; once grasped it is trivial, but then again, everything is after you understand it--by definition!)

Comment: @Sjoerd, Please see the Edit, could you tell me what I am doing wrong why the point in upper left are represented in lower right ? How could I get the polar plot to match the plot I have shown ?

Comment: @500 The code I gave is for angles results sorted from 0 to 2 pi whereas you have the angles going from -pi to +pi. If you want to use my function unedited you'll have to `RotateRight` your dataset so that it starts with angle 0. Alternatively, you can subtract pi from the angles in my code. BTW I think you should use the Disk version of the plot. The more I see the Polygon version the more I think it's ugly. (it's the flat top together with the rings that creates an illusion of the top bending inwards).

Comment: @Sjoerd, check this out. Do you see any potential/way in/of adapting this ? : SectorChart[RandomReal[10, {10, 2}],  PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
 PolarTicks -> {Drop[Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}], -1], Automatic}]

Comment: @500 I'd looked at that before and thought it would't work as the primary input seemed to be width and height of the sectors, not direction.  But I now realize that you can do this with the option SectorOrigin. I'll come up with an example asap

Comment: @Sjoerd, Thank you, once again, very much !

Comment: @Sjoerd, I am sorry I spent hours trying to make it work with my data but each time the binning goes wrong. RotateRight does not work, neither does Reverse. I am sorry, but could you make your exemple starting with coordinate and not Bins ? I am literally going insane, I don`t understand what goes wrong :-(

Comment: @Sjoerd, It is hard I cannot tell myself I won`t use your plot. They look so good, however each time I try I fail to get those straight. What I don`t understand is that Arctan gives us result from -Pi to Pi and I could not find any source telling me how to go from this to 0-2Pi ?

Comment: @500 You should know that angles remain the same when a multiple of 2 pi is added. So an angle of -pi/2 is also 3/2 pi. Another point is that I have the first sector centred around zero degrees whereas you end one at zero and start one at zero. Anyway, the following should work for you:

Comment: @500  Using your previous definition of c1: `ListPolarPlot[{{0, maxScale}}, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
    FontSize -> 12}, PlotStyle -> {None}, 
  Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Blue, EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.005]}], 
    Table[Disk[{0, 0}, 
      c1[[ang + 1]], {ang dAng - \[Pi], 
       ang dAng - \[Pi] + dAng}], {ang, 0, angleDivisions - 1}]}] /. 
 Style[num_?MachineNumberQ, List[]] :> Style[num // Round, List[]]`

Comment: @Sjoerd, thank you very much, sorry I did not know if you were around and wanted to see the result of this plot so much. I believe this is one of my best plot.

Answer (score 5):

That seems to be the [polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). The Cartesian-to-polar conversion formulas are [in that same article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates):

[image]

This returns the angle in radians.

Comment: To add to Blender's answer, use the two parameter form of [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArcTan.html) as it automatically accounts for the quadrant.

Comment: Thank You, What would be the best way to set ScreenCenter = {20, 15} as my origin for the conversion ?

Comment: Replace all the `y`s with `y + ScreenCenter.y` and do similarly for `x`.

Answer (score 5):

This

```
N@ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ (# - ScreenCenter & /@ dalist)
```

returns the list of angles of the ray from `ScreenCenter` to each point, in radians and between -pi and pi.

That is, I assumed you want the angle between each point in your plot and the red dot.

Note the use of `ArcTan[x,y]` rather than `ArcTan[y/x]`, which automatically chooses the appropriate sign (otherwise you'd have to do it by hand, as in @Blender's answer).

Comment: I am sorry I am going crazy. When i try to implement with you solution or Sjoerd and can`t draw hi histogram with either on my actual data the quadrant are visually wrong. I am so confused, could you show me an example ? For me Upper left if down right, Upper Right, down left.

Comment: @500 I don't understand what you are asking! What is "implement" here? Did you understand that these are angles, in radians, from -pi to pi and measured from the x-axis?