# PolarTicks, Polar GridLines & Background customization

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

Building up on 
[From Cartesian Plot to Polar Histogram using  Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419562/from-cartesian-plot-to-polar-histogram-using-mathematica) I would like to customize the R and theta Axes :

please consider :

```
list = {{21, 16}, {16, 14}, {11, 11}, {11, 12}, {13, 15}, {18,17}, {19, 11}, {17, 16}, {16, 19}}

Module[{Countz, maxScale, angleDivisions, dAng}, 
        maxScale = 4;
        angleDivisions = 12;
        dAng = (2 \[Pi])/angleDivisions;
        Countz = BinCounts[ Flatten@Map[ArcTan @@ (# - ScreenCenter) &, list, {1}], 
                            {-Pi, Pi,dAng}];

        SectorChart[{ConstantArray[1, Length[Countz]], Countz}\[Transpose], 
        SectorOrigin -> {-\[Pi]/angleDivisions, "Counterclockwise"}, 
        PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
        PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 5},
        PolarTicks -> {Table[{i \[Degree] + \[Pi]/angleDivisions, i \[Degree]}, 
                       {i, 0, 345, 30}], Range[5]}, 
        ChartStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.005]}], Red]},
        BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
        FontSize -> 12}, ImageSize -> 400, 
        ChartElementFunction -> Function[{range}, 
                                Disk[{0, 0}, range[[2, 2]], -11 Pi/12 + range[[1]]]]]]
```

[image]

2/I would like to add one "theta bar" colored at 45 Degree (as shown in the image). However I did that using ppt. I could not find a mean to keep the Table to get the main theta axes and draw another one colored differently.

[image]

3/I failed to adapt the solution provided on [Customsize Backgroud in Plot within Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300229/customsize-backgroud-in-plot-within-mathematica) to a Polarplot using Prolog. Is it possible to have the area within the outer circle of the plot colored in Gray let`s say ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Epilog` to create the line and `Prolog` for the background, e.g.

```
Module[{Countz, maxScale, angleDivisions, dAng}, maxScale = 4;
 angleDivisions = 12;
 dAng = (2 \[Pi])/angleDivisions;
 Countz = 
  BinCounts[
   Flatten@Map[ArcTan @@ (# - ScreenCenter) &, list, {1}], {-Pi, Pi, dAng}];

 SectorChart[{ConstantArray[1, Length[Countz]], Countz}\[Transpose], 
  SectorOrigin -> {-\[Pi]/angleDivisions, "Counterclockwise"}, 
  PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 5}, 
  PolarTicks -> {Table[{i \[Degree] + \[Pi]/angleDivisions, 
      i \[Degree]}, {i, 0, 345, 30}], Range[5]}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.005]}], Red]},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  ChartElementFunction -> 
   Function[{range}, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, range[[2, 2]], -11 Pi/12 + range[[1]]]],
  Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, 5/Sqrt[2] {1, 1}}]},
  Prolog -> {Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 5]}]]
```

[image: sectorchart with line and gray background]

Comment: Heike, How can I adapt the angle of the line, for let`s 37.5 Degree ? I don`t understand in which coordinate system this line is.Many Thanks.

Comment: @500 In the Epilog: `Line[{0,0}, r {Cos@Phi,Sin@Phi}]` where `r` is the radius and `Phi` is your angle

Comment: @belisarius, thank you. I think it needs {} to make it works. Also I am still confuse, the angle are in degrees to me yet. in which format shall phi be ?